Add film grain in Blender video editing
I'm working on a personal short film, and I wanted to add a film grain effect in the video sequence editor (after my renders .exr, so I can adjust the effect as I want).
I use the ACES workflow.
I downloaded a 35mm Film Grain footage here, and I wanted to add it in the video editing.
I use the source file and selected Overlay in the blend mode, but the result is weird.
Without film grain.

With film grain, blend mode: overlay, value=0.371.

I don't know why I get these high values.
Also, I tried directly in the compositing panel, I mixed this image with the film grain footage in overlay mode, and I don't have this issue. The film grain worked as intented (I maxed out the effect so you can see the behavior).

But when I toggle the clamp, I get the similar issue with picture 2.

How can I remove the clamp option of my compositing strip in the visual sequence editor?

This question is similar to: How to add film grain using the compositor. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I edit my question with more details. And my issue is with my strip in the video sequence editor.

Not 100% sure, but it seems like a color management issue to me.
On the Scene
Your whole scene is set to work and output a specific color space.
In the Render properties, make sure your color management is set to View Transform: Standard, and Sequencer: sRGB.

This would be done automatically when creating a new file using the Video Editing preset (from the splash screen or the new file menu):

On the strips
Each strip you add in the VSE can use a different color space depending on the source.
Blender's EXR files are saved in a scene-linear color space based on the Rec.709, meaning the pixel values represent linear light intensities with no gamma correction or display transform applied (I.E. no AGX nor Filmic). So if those EXRs weren't tempered outside of Blender, make sure your EXR file's strip have its Color Space property set to "Linear Rec.709":

Checking your grain file's metadata in MediaInfo reveal its color management to be "BT.709", aka Rec.709 (not Linear), which is Blender's "sRGB" color space, and should be the default one when adding video strips to your VSE, but it doesn't hurt to check it's there:

Final note
Using the Sequence Editor to stack a strip of grain texture over your EXR's strip with overlay mode should work, though I suspect an opacity of 0.001 will not be enough to notice anything, even in dark tones. At least could use values up to 0.5 depending on what I overlay it on and how much noise I want.


Thank you for your extend answer! I edited my question with more details, and I use the ACES workflow in Blender.
